# How to setup Nexus OSS in order to use docker proxy credentials

Tags: docker, nexus

I've purchased a Docker account and setup my Docker proxy using Nexus OSS as following :

Repositories -> Create a Docker Proxy -> Select Use Docker Hub (Remote Storage : https://registry-1.docker.io) -> with Authentication Enabled (providing username/password of Docker)

And inside my client I configured it to use my Nexus as registry mirror using following command :

```
systemctl edit docker
```

then added:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --registery-mirror=https://myprivatenexus.com
```

Yet when I'm trying to use "*docker pull*" inside my client I'll get the annoying "Docker Hub Pull Limits" error.

Is it possible to use my Docker account inside Nexus or should I try something else?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a type-O in your ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd where `--registery-mirror` should be `--registry-mirror`

Answer (score 1):

We used Nexus at work in a similar setting. Your nexus configuration looks like ours. For me the client mirror configuration looks strange. If I access a nexus repository without any configured connectors the I have to configure on client side the whole context path.

After your screenshot: `https://YOUR_SERVER/repository/DockerHub`

If you would connect a dedicated repository connector e.g. http/8088, then you could configure your client with

`http://YOUR_SERVER:8088`

[The documentation from sonatype](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/ssl-and-repository-connector-configuration) describes the same:

*A configured context-path for the user interface does not affect the repository connector URLs used by Docker. E.g. if your repository manager instance is configured to be available at http://localhost:8081/nexus instead of the default root context http://localhost:8081/, the URLs for your Docker repositories will still only use the configured port for the repository and omit the context path in the URL. This is a side-effect of the the fact that Docker does not support context paths in the registry API.*